# How to update an value in app.config file?

Tags: c#

This is my code:

```
Configuration configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
KeyValueConfigurationCollection settings = configuration.AppSettings.Settings;  
settings["IP"].Value = "10.0.0.2";
configuration.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
```

when I break on `settings["IP"].Value` line, i get the correct value.
The method completes without any errors but app.config file remains unchanged.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This code should work:

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

config.AppSettings.Settings["IP"].Value = "10.0.0.2";
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
```

Comment: You have to run the executable file in your /bin/release folder (eg: Console01.exe), and check the app.config file in the same folder(eg: Console01.exe.Config)

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge `you can't persist the updated value in App.config`. 
If you want to persist the config value,do the normal XML operation.