# C# WinForms changing database name in other form

Tags: c#, winforms, connection-string

So here is my first question and my first C# program:

I need function that could permanently change a connection string.

My program has this structure:
Main form is `Form1`, when I click the button, `Options`, I get new from - `Form3`, where user can log in (password protects changing options) and if login is successfull I create new form - `Form4`. In constructor of `Form4`, I pass a `SqlConnection` object from `Form1`. I want to change my database name by clicking on button, so here is the code:

```
var config = ConfigurationManager
.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

var connectionStringsSection = (ConnectionStringsSection)config
.GetSection("connectionStrings");

var x = connectionStringsSection
.ConnectionStrings["App.Properties.Settings.ppsConnectionString"]
.ConnectionString;

String[] words = x.Split(';');

words[1] = "Initial Catalog="+textBoxDB.Text;
x=String.Join(";", words);

connectionStringsSection
.ConnectionStrings["App.Properties.Settings.ppsConnectionString"]
.ConnectionString = x;
//above, this variable x in debug mode looks right
//I read this line below should update file, so change would be permamently
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");
```

But it doesn't change anything, and I have no idea how to change this Settings file so user could change database name and when they restart the app, they should have this new changed connection string.

**EDIT :**

Thanks for the responses it turns out that I should run this code from bin/Release .exe version, not under Debug in VS and it actually changes this config file.

Comment: Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838027/how-to-update-an-value-in-app-config-file - and really, a google search will show a ton of results on how to update the config file from C#.

Comment: Well I did not see the comments, there was a tricky detail

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual Studio then you can set a range of settings within your executable using the Properties form of the Project and these settings can be accessed without reflection. These properties can be made 'application level' or 'user level' so determining how wide a ranging any changes would be.

YourProjectName.Properties.Settings.Default.YourSettingName = "A Setting";

This is good if you know how many ConnectionStrings and other variables you want to store, if you require to set an unknown number of connection strings then I personally would use a DataTable with Rows for each setting, which can be saved to an XML file in your applications directory, or per user.

Answer (score 0):

Store your configuration data in a singleton configuration object and use the connection string from there. Init the singleton object during startup with your connectionstring from app.config and change it later on.