# Updating App.Config from c# method

Tags: c#, appdomain

I am trying to use the following code to update my app config from a windows form

```
public void UpdateConfigFile(string con)
        {
            //updating config file
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();        
            //Loading the Config file
            xmlDoc.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);
            if (xmlDoc.DocumentElement != null)
                foreach (XmlElement xElement in xmlDoc.DocumentElement)
                {
                    if (xElement.Name == "connectionStrings")
                    {
                        //setting the coonection string
                        if (xElement.FirstChild.Attributes != null) xElement.FirstChild.Attributes[2].Value = con;
                    }
                }
            //writing the connection string in config file
            xmlDoc.Save(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);
        }
```

Not sure if I'm missing the point but I expected to see the app.config file update within my solution. However the code actually updates my C:\Users\temp\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\SequoiaToolbox2014MvvM\SequoiaToolbox2014MvvM\bin\Debug\SequoiaToolbox2014MvvM.vshost.exe.config and has no impact on the app.con file?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838027/how-to-update-an-value-in-app-config-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are building and running from Debug mode. By default, the Debug mode uses the VSHost .exe and .config to improve startup time and debugging time. Since it is updating this temporary file, you are not seeing the changes in your expected file.

To get it working properly, you need to do one of 2 things:

1. Run in Release mode
2. Turn this behaviour off by following the guidance at this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185330.aspx):

> To disable the hosting process
>
> 1. Open an executable project in Visual Studio. Projects that do not produce executables (for example, class library or service projects)
>      do not have this option.
> 2. On the Project menu, click Properties.
> 3. Click the Debug tab.
> 4. Clear the Enable the Visual Studio hosting process check box.
>
> When the hosting process is disabled, several debugging features are
>   unavailable or experience decreased performance. For more information,
>   see Debugging and the Hosting Process.

Comment: If you want to avoid disabling VS hosting, could you just read the config file by name instead of getting `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile`?